# How often is fine used to describe a good person during greetings?

Tags: adjectives

It is very common to be greeted with a question about being 'fine'. For example, "are you fine" today? How are you? Are you alright? Are you okay? These example questions all ask about being fine.

Many dictionaries would make 'fine' to mean satisfactory as with ['alright'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all%20right#:%7E:text=%3A-,SATISFACTORY,-%2C%20AGREEABLE). However 'fine' can also refer to a permanent characteristic as an [adjective](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fine#:%7E:text=A-,fine,-person%20is%20someone).

The clear distinction is to use 'fine' to mean being in either a temporary satisfactory state or a permanently good state. As 'to be' is a verb which truly [always](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/verbs/linking-verbs.html?fbclid=IwAR15BUlgeCaKnLlIBIolwzzCZouTnjDe43uRvPn5r8X0OcCSnhUiiPLTCtU#:%7E:text=Some%20words%20are-,always,-linking%20verbs.%20These) links the subject to complementary information it doesn't describe doing an action in a certain way. 'To be' sometimes seems to be referring to a permanent state as with an [adjective](https://mcelroytutoring.com/blog-post.php?id=4163&fbclid=IwAR0yLlxAlnu46bh_8uICeuYhhmjlvA9hARZ76hht2SI5DBWqygJ0BTwQ4us#:%7E:text=we%20should%20use-,adjectives,-%2C%20to%20describe%20ourselves) being connected to the subject. For example, you are a 'fine' person.

So how often does 'alright', 'okay' and 'fine' refer to an 'alright', 'okay' and 'fine' person during greetings?

Comment: Could you clarify? Nobody assumes that a person is an "alright person" because that person said he was feeling "alright".

Comment: Actually @FeliniusRex my point is the total opposite to yours. Perhaps that person is an 'alright' person?

Comment: To answer your question, OP, never. If someone says they are "doing alright" that in no way means that they are an "alright" person.

Comment: A human 'being' is not a human 'doing'. The two verbs 'being' and "doing" are different to each other in terms of their functions. 'Doing' describes an action it sometimes has an adverb after it. 'Being' is not about an action it is sometimes about an inherent quality.

Comment: Ok, I give up. I've answered your question. So has Ethan below.

Comment: Nobody asks "Are you fine today?" It might be "How are you?" or "How's things?" or "Are you well?" and they usually don't want to know the answer, so you say "Great! You?" and so on. It's a *greeting* not an enquiry into someone's health.

Comment: You are over-thinking the implications of the reply "I am fine". It never means "I am a fine or good person" unless they are terribly conceited. The whole exchange is just a quick little "Hello" exchange. And if the question is intended to express concern and some discussion, it should be inverted: "Are you unwell today?" but only if you know the person well.

Answer (score 4):

When someone asks

> "are you fine" today? How are you? Are you alright? Are you okay?

they want information about your particular status that day. Perhaps you look tired, or you were recently ill.

Your answer (should you choose to respond) addresses that state. Neither the question nor the answer has anything to do with what kind of person you are.

Comment: I have _never_, to my knowledge, heard anyone ask "Are you fine?", but I have often replied to the greeting "How are you?" with "I'm fine, thanks", meaning "I'm perfectly well", not "I am a fine person"!